# Sql get middle records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem with mySQL query.

My table:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
| id | user_id | name   | assigned_at | unassigned_at |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 20      | TEST   | 2018-12-12  | null          |
| 2  | 20      | TEST 2 | 2018-12-01  | 2018-12-12    | 
| 3  | 20      | TEST 3 | 2018-11-20  | 2018-12-01    |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

How I can get records by date? Like example I want get records number 2

But I need use `user_id where_in('20', '30', '33', '20')`

Comment: I doubt that the sample data (and desired result) is fairly representative of the problem. See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: `I want get records number 2`? What qualifies that record to return? This is not related to PHP. Please add your current query and explain what should happen and why.

Comment: "I have a problem with mySQL query"...what query? You didn't show us any query. What have you done? Why exactly should record 2 be the one to be selected here? What is special about it? In other words...you need to tell us the full rules for your query.

Answer (score 2):

You can add filtering by date column in WHERE statement

```
SELECT * 
FROM <your table>
WHERE assigned_at = '2018-12-01'
   AND user_id IN ('20', '30', '33')
```

Comment: `2018-12-01` that should be quoted. Otherwise, mysql will interpret that as doing math/minuses. Edit: this comment as per the original https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/53744247/1

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner oh of course. I fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Ok. Not my downvote here btw. Edit: which someone removed.

Comment: This seems to answer the question.